# Check if any of array elements starts with specific characters postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to check if an array has any of elements which starts with or ends with the string specified.

For Comparing strings we could do something like below,

`select * from table where 'gggggg' ilike '%g';`

Can someone help to find out if an array contains values as like pattern.
Eg array : ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']

Also I want to find if any of elements ends with 1 or starts with 'str'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, the only thing you can do is unnest the array and test each element:

```
create table test (a text[]);

insert into test values (array['abc', 'def', 'ghi']);

select distinct a from test
JOIN lateral (select * from unnest(a) as u) as sub on TRUE
WHERE u like '%g';
 a
---
(0 rows)

select distinct a from test
JOIN lateral (select * from unnest(a) as u) as sub on TRUE
WHERE u like 'g%';
       a
---------------
 {abc,def,ghi}
(1 row)
```

In postgres 12, you will be able to use jsonb_path_exists.  Of course, this would work better if you stored your data in jsonb, but it will still work, just not as efficiently:

```
-- Starts with g
select a from test 
where jsonb_path_exists(to_jsonb(a), '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "^g")');
       a
---------------
 {abc,def,ghi}
(1 row)

-- Ends with g
select a from test 
where jsonb_path_exists(to_jsonb(a), '$[*] ? (@ like_regex "g$")');
 a
---
(0 rows)
```